# Python - Beautifulsoup to PDF with picture (relative paths)

Tags: python, html, pdf, path, beautifulsoup

I use mechanize for browse a website. After this, I use beautifulsoup for manipulatting the content of a webpage (convert to unicode, remove some lines). Now I want to create of PDF file from the html source obtain with Beautifulsoup. Iuse pdfkit and it works fine for the text. But now I want to create also pdf with pictures which are in the html code. The url are specified (also for pictures) by using a relative path '../../' etc.

How can I change all the url for considering absolute paths and how can I obtain the pictures in the pdf files? Will be the change of the path sufficient for obtaining the pictures?

**SOLUTION:** (based on dudu1791 proposal)

```
#changement liens vers images
def ChangeLinkIMG(soup,baseurl):
    #parcours des images
    for imgLK in soup.findAll('img'):    
        #chemin relatif image
        try:
            relaIMG=imgLK['src'] 
            #creation lien absolu
            absoIMG=urljoin(baseurl,relaIMG)
            imgLK['src']=absoIMG
            print absoIMG
        except:
            pass
    return soup
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its probably half the answer, but the below code can help you turn url for considering absolute paths. This is how I have done it.

```
def parse_all_links(self, soup):            
        for link in soup.find_all('a'):                
            if(link.get('href')):
                href = link.get('href')
                if href.startswith('http') or href.startswith('https'):
                    print(href)                        
                elif href =='#':
                    #print('No link present')
                    pass
                elif href =='/':
                    pass
                else:
                    href = baseurl + href
                    print(href)
```

Comment: Thank you! I modify your proposal for dealing with pictures. I wrote my function in my post.